# How and should I turn my html page to react components?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-component

Trying to make a react app using pre made sources. I have a fully functional web page made in vanila js.  Is the best approach (or maybe the only one) to turn the html page into multiple react components and just delete the html page or should I maybe find a way to just implement react code into html?

Comment: Check this link from [medium](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-convert-any-web-page-to-reactjs-9740f1ba15db)

Answer (score 1):

Why write 5 times the same button when you can write it once and import it the rest 4 times? This assures a unified look on your site and that any minor change you make will be reflected in all the proper places.

Consider a testimonial slider. You want this in your home page and in your about page. Why have the need to update it in two places?

If you are going the React way I will suggest to go all the way. Componetize your site, see the true power of React. Maybe its an overkill for your site (every component appears once -doubt-) but if this is the case you will start learning a really powerful tool with a simple example and the progressively get better.